# Partitioned-View not working with parameters

Tags: sql-server, partitioned-view

We currenlty have a few customers where their querys would take ages to get results out of a partitioned view. On closer inspection we found the execution plan to scan every table, instead of just the ones with the relevant data.

To isolate this behaviour, I took the partitioned view example from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx and recreated our problem:

In this example, we have 12 tables (for each month of the year 1998):

```
CREATE TABLE Jan1998sales
(
    OrderID INT,
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL,
    OrderDate DATETIME NULL CHECK(DATEPART(yy, OrderDate) = 1998),
    OrderMonth INT CHECK (OrderMonth = 1),
    DeliveryDate DATETIME NULL CHECK(DATEPART(MM, DeliveryDate) = 1),
    CONSTRAINT Jan1998sales_OrderIDMonth PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, OrderMonth)
)
```

We are looking at a view that looks as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW Year1998Sales
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Jan1998Sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Feb1998Sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Mar1998Sales
    UNION ALL
    [...]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Dec1998Sales
)
```

Now we have one query that works perfectly fine (only scans the necessary tables):

```
SELECT * FROM Year1998Sales
WHERE (OrderMonth = 5 OR OrderMonth = 6) AND CustomerID = 64892
```

But if we filter with parameters, it suddently scans all tables:

```
DECLARE @MonthA int = 5
DECLARE @MonthB int = 6

SELECT * FROM Year1998Sales
WHERE (OrderMonth = @MonthA OR OrderMonth = @MonthB) AND CustomerID = 64892
```

My first guess to explain this behaviour would be that the Microsoft SQL Server builds a execution plan once, which scans all tables, and reuses this for every execution of this query, thus is scanning all tables at all times.

Does anyone know how we could get the SQL Server to only scan the necessary tables and still use a parameterized filter?
Or can anyone confirm that this is a bug in the SQL Server execution plan builder?

For the full code have a look at this SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e1f33/1

Comment: This is not an answer, but storing each month's sales in a separate table seems slightly off to me.  If you had all sales in one table, you probably would not have this exact problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As already stated this is just an example for partitioned views that allows to recreate our problem fairly easily. But even though, you can get quite a huge performance boost if you split the data up in seperate tables for each month.

Comment: Of course it scans all tables.  Why would the SQL Server engine assume that `Jan1998Sales` wouldn't have orders from month 5 and 6?  *You* know that, but the query engine doesn't.  It has to check every time.  It may help to have an index on (CustomerID, OrderMonth) on each table, but otherwise I'd expect a full scan.

Comment: @BaconBits Because the Check-Constraints in the table ensure that it only contains the data for its month. The first query shows that this works if you provide the value directly, but not if you are using parameters.

Comment: Parameters often give these kinds of unexpected results, especially as you're doing something that's very non-standard. If you're willing to ditch the view, you could probably do something with a CTE and a lot of CASE statements. It'd be pretty horrible code though.

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError, try adding the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint to see if you get static partition elimination with the `OR` clause.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misread the query that was working fine.  I thought it was querying one of the month tables!

Comment: @Simon I would say this is quite standard, as I only want to select certain data from a partitioned view. If this is not the standard use for partitioned views, what is?

Comment: @DanGuzman I tried that, but it does not change anything.

Comment: @BaconBits No problem. As you see, both querys do the exact same thing, but the execution plan builder does not seem to work well with parameters and partitioned views.

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError, what SQL Server version are you using? I get elimination with the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint under SQL 2012+ versions of SQL Server with latest service packs.

Comment: @DanGuzman I tried your suggestion on the SQL Fiddle, which uses an Microsoft SQL Server 2014, but I can not ensure that the latest service packs were installed. After your recent comment, I verified this with my MS SQL Server 2017 RC2 and indeed, it helps! Thanks a lot! If you commit it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError, thanks for the confirmation. Added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, `OR` predicates are challenging for SQL Server to optimize and generate a reusable cached plan.

I ran the query with the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint and the actual execution plan shows unneeded partitioned view member tables are statically eliminated from the plan. Not sure why sqlfiddle doesn't show this (it's currently using SQL 2014 RTM) but I observed elimination with all versions of SQL Server from 2012 through 2017 RC2 with latest service packs installed.

```
DECLARE @MonthA int = 5
DECLARE @MonthB int = 6;

SELECT *
FROM Year1998Sales
WHERE (OrderMonth = @MonthA OR OrderMonth = @MonthB) AND CustomerID = 64892
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Here's the actual execution plan XML (SQL Server 2017 RC2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.6" Build="14.0.900.75" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="3" StatementEstRows="2" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="140" StatementSubTreeCost="0.00656736" StatementText="SELECT *&#xD;&#xA;FROM Year1998Sales&#xD;&#xA;WHERE (OrderMonth = @MonthA OR OrderMonth = @MonthB) AND CustomerID = 64892&#xD;&#xA;OPTION(RECOMPILE)" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0xF9DB04D00D56A43D" QueryPlanHash="0x6171395FA7A2F92C" RetrievedFromCache="false" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="8" CompileCPU="8" CompileMemory="552">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="419405" EstimatedPagesCached="104851" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" MaxCompileMemory="9985376" />
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="0" ElapsedTime="0" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="35" EstimateCPU="2E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="2" LogicalOp="Concatenation" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Concatenation" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00656736">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Union1014" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Union1015" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Union1016" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Union1017" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Union1018" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Concat>
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Union1014" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderID" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Union1015" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="CustomerID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="CustomerID" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Union1016" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderDate" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderDate" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Union1017" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderMonth" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderMonth" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Union1018" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="DeliveryDate" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="DeliveryDate" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="35" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" EstimatedRowsRead="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="0">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="CustomerID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderDate" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderMonth" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="DeliveryDate" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderID" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="CustomerID" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderDate" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="OrderMonth" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="DeliveryDate" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Index="[May1998sales_OrderIDMonth]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                    <Predicate>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Repro].[dbo].[May1998sales].[CustomerID]=(64892)">
                        <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Identifier>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[May1998sales]" Column="CustomerID" />
                            </Identifier>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Const ConstValue="(64892)" />
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Compare>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Predicate>
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="35" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" EstimatedRowsRead="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="0">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="CustomerID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderDate" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderMonth" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="DeliveryDate" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderID" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="CustomerID" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderDate" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="OrderMonth" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="DeliveryDate" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Index="[Jun1998sales_OrderIDMonth]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                    <Predicate>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Repro].[dbo].[Jun1998sales].[CustomerID]=(64892)">
                        <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Identifier>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[Repro]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Jun1998sales]" Column="CustomerID" />
                            </Identifier>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Const ConstValue="(64892)" />
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Compare>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Predicate>
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
              </Concat>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```